# Internal angles in regular 18-gon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons, plane-geometry, angle

This (seemingly simple) problem is driving me nuts.

> Find angle $\alpha$ shown in the following regular 18-gon.

[image]

It was easy to find the angle between pink diagonals ($60^\circ$). And I was able to solve the problem with some trigonometry (getting nice integer angle). However, all my attempts to solve the problem without use of trigonometry have failed. It looked like I was close to solution all the time (so many angles are equal to $60^\circ$ or $120^\circ$. I felt like I had to draw just one more line and the problem would break apart. I also tried with internal symmetries and rotations but eventually I had to give up.

Is there a way to solve this kind of problem without sines and cosines?

Comment: You should mention what the "nice integer angle" is, to save people some time.

Comment: It's $20^\circ$. Even more interesting is that if you extend the black line to the southeast it will pass through a vertex of the polygon.

Comment: Say, the triangle with $\alpha$ has vertices $A_1,A_2$ from the 18-gon. You claim the black line is $A_2A_8$. Once it's known, we can finish by observing $A_2A_8\parallel A_3A_7$ and $A_1A_7A_3\angle =20^\circ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a direct solution. The best I have relates to a different problem, so I show the latter's solution, then show how the two problems correspond.

**Lemma.** Let $OAC$ be a triangle, and $X$ a point in it, and let angles $CAX=40^{\circ}, XAO=10^{\circ}, AOX=10^{\circ}, XOC=70^{\circ}$. What is $\angle OCX$?

[image: solution of lemma]

**Solution of lemma.**
$\angle AOC=80^{\circ}$ and $\angle CAO=50^{\circ}$ so $\angle OCA=50^{\circ}= \angle CAO$ so $\triangle ACO$ is isosceles on base $AC$, so $OA=OC$.

$\angle AOX = 10^{\circ} = \angle XAO$, so $\triangle OAX$ is isosceles on base $OA$, so $AX=OX$.

$\angle OXA = 180^{\circ} - \angle XAO - \angle AOX = 160^{\circ}$.

Erect an equilateral $\triangle OXE$ on base $OX$. Join $CE$.
$\angle EOC = \angle XOC - \angle XOE = 70^{\circ} - 60^{\circ} = 10^{\circ} = \angle AOX$.
Thus $\triangle$s $OAX, OCE$ are congruent (SAS, opposite sense) because $\angle EOC = \angle AOX, OA=OC$ and $OX=OE$.
Thus $\angle OCE = \angle XAO = 10^{\circ}$.
$CE=AX=OX=XE$.
Thus $\triangle XCE$ is isosceles on base $XC$.
$\angle XEC = 360^{\circ} - \angle CEO - \angle OEX = 360^{\circ} - 160^{\circ} - 60^{\circ} = 140^{\circ}$.
Thus $\angle ECX = (180^{\circ}-140^{\circ})/2 = 20^{\circ}$.
Thus $\angle OCX = \angle ECX + \angle OCE = 20^{\circ}+10^{\circ} = 30^{\circ}$, which solves the lemma.

[image: solution of original problem]

**Solution of the original problem.**
Let $P_0\dots P_{17}$ be a regular 18-gon. Let $P_1P_{13}$ cross $P_{5}P_{15}$ at $X$. What is $\alpha=\angle P_0XP_1$?

Let the centre of the 18-gon be $O$. $\triangle P_0P_{1}O$ is isosceles on base $P_{0}P_1$, and $\angle P_0OP_1=20^\circ$, so $\angle OP_1P_0=80^\circ$.

$\triangle P_{13}P_1O$ is isosceles on base $P_{13}P_1$, and $\angle P_{13}OP_1=120^\circ$, so $\angle OP_1P_{13}=30^\circ=\angle OP_1X$ as $X$ is on $P_1P_{13}$.

$\triangle P_{15}P_5O$ is isosceles on base $P_{15}P_5$, and $\angle P_{15}OP_5=160^\circ$, so $\angle P_5P_{15}O=10^\circ=\angle XP_{15}O$ as $X$ is on $P_5P_{15}$.

$\triangle P_{15}P_1O$ is isosceles on base $P_{15}P_1$, and $\angle P_{15}OP_1=80^\circ$, so $\angle P_1P_{15}O=50^\circ$. Thus this $\triangle$ has the same angles $80^\circ, 50^\circ, 50^\circ$ as the lemma's $\triangle OAC$, so they are similar. Moreover, the angles $OP_1X=30^\circ$ and $XP_{15}O=10^\circ$ correspond to those in the lemma, so the $X$s correspond. Therefore, by the lemma, $OX=XP_{15}$.

$OP_0=OP_{15}$ and $\angle P_{15}OP_0=60^\circ$ so $\triangle OP_{15}P_0$ is equilateral. Thus $\triangle$s $OXP_0$ and $P_{15}XP_0$ are congruent in opposite senses (SSS) because $OX=XP_{15}$, $OP_0=P_{15}P_0$ and $P_0X$ is common. Thus $\angle OP_0X=\angle XP_0P_{15}$ so $\angle OP_0X=30^\circ=\angle OP_1X$, so quadrilateral $OXP_0P_1$ is cyclic, so $\alpha=\angle P_0XP_1=\angle P_0OP_1=20^\circ$, which solves the problem.